# What is radar minima?

Tags: terminology, aeronautical-charts

I was studying the Aeronautical Chart User's Guide and I came across the term 'radar minima' several times under the graphics depicting charted airports.

> Blue – Airports with an Instrument Approach Procedure and/or
>   RADAR MINIMA published in the high altitude DoD Flight
>   Information Publications (FLIPs)
>
> Green – Airports which have an approved Instrument Approach
>   Procedure and/or RADAR MINIMA published in either the
>   U.S. Terminal Procedures Publications (TPPs) or the DoD FLIPs
>
> Brown – Airports without a published Instrument Approach
>   Procedure or RADAR MINIMA

Comment: The FAA Pilot/Controller glossary doesn't define the term "radar minima", although the term "minima" redirects to "minimums". Its possible this either refers to radar separation minimums or minimum vectoring altitude (MVA), but I can't verify that.

Comment: (US) Radar minimums are published in the [TPP](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/). Here is a [snapshot for Elmendorf Anchorage AFB](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xgLar.png), available on [FlightAware](https://www.flightaware.com/resources/airport/PAED/MIN/all/pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Published minimums for an [ASR or PAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveillance_radar_approach) approach.

An ASR is essentially a non-precision approach with an MDA, while a PAR is a precision approach (found almost exclusively at military fields) with minimums of 200 and 1/2.

Comment: you can always ask for a "no gyro" practice approach. the ex-military controllers love them, and I think they're fun to do